# Is there a standard for mentioning variables within comments?

Tags: c, comments, documentation

I understand that, in principle, modern programming languages are intended to be used in a manner where the code written is self-documenting.

However, I was taught that on occasion it is necessary to explicitly write a brief precondition, postcondition statement for a function to assert generality. If I had a need to mention a variable by name in the comment is there a standard for denoting that it's a variable?

Comment: Doxygen perhaps?

Comment: I've started using markdown. Snippets or var names are placed in backticks. It doesn't denote a variable specifically, but it does indicate the word doesn't have its normal English meaning.

Comment: @ikegami "Snippets or var names are placed in backticks." --> quite reasonable, yet _backtick_ is not a portable character (also _$_, _@_) to use in C source code - leads to UB.  See C17dr 5.2.1

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: what UB are you referring to? 5.2.1 says: *If any other characters are encountered in a source file (except in an identifier, a character constant, a string literal, a header name, a comment, or a preprocessing token that is never converted to a token), the behavior is undefined.*

Comment: @chqrlie  I seriously doubt any `'`, `$`, `@` will cause undesirable effects.

Answer (score 0):

Please use [doxygen](https://www.doxygen.nl/) for C, it is the de-facto-standard and worth the effort.

https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html

> \pre { description of the precondition }
>
> Starts a paragraph where the
> precondition of an entity can be described. The paragraph will be
> indented. The text of the paragraph has no special internal structure.
> All visual enhancement commands may be used inside the paragraph.
> Multiple adjacent \pre commands will be joined into a single
> paragraph. Each precondition will start on a new line. Alternatively,
> one \pre command may mention several preconditions. The \pre command
> ends when a blank line or some other sectioning command is
> encountered.

Comment: I've never used Doxygen before so I watched a tutorial. The functionality is cool but it looks like it deteriorates your source codes readability with dozens of comment lines. Are these meant to be suppressed?

Comment: No, they are not meant to be suppressed. Unfortunately, I do not know of a better way to keep source code and (generate-able) documentation in sync.